# Wix - Get user input to create a registry entry

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I need to create an installer that gets the user input to create a registry entry. I've looked into Wix tutorials and it's very clear how to install registry entries but I need the user to give some info(in this case it's an url) so that url can be used on the registry entry.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate question!?

Please take a look at this answer if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20679626/1331719

**Edit** - slightly modifying the answer found in the link:

Start by adding this component, notice the property in Value `[USERINPUT]`

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
  <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="{YOURGUID}">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Company123\App123" Action="create">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="UserInput" Value="[USERINPUT]" />
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Reference the component in your feature:

```
<Feature>
    <ComponentRef Id="RegistryEntries" />
    ...
</Feature>
```

Get user input when you install using msiexec:

```
msiexec /i your.msi /qb+ USERINPUT="http://urlYouWantToStoreIn.Registry"
```

Check registry HKLM\Software\Company123\App123\UserInput, the url should be there.

Comment: I had a look at this answer before but it's getting info from another regsitry not the users input

Comment: That answer uses two msis, one is to store whatever string in registry which should answer your question and the second msi is to read that value, in your case just skip the second msi.

Comment: thank you. It seems the right answer, Windows Installer is not really my thing so I probably didn't understand the other question correctly. Thanks again!